# Order of learning mantras

Tags: mantras, astrology, gayatri-mantra

I'm a 42 yr male looking to learn some chants. Assuming i know nothing, what can be the correct order of learning chants? 
Nothing is too small - right from one shloka to big chants, how to approach learning?

Is there a jyotish approach? like my nakshatra or lord of lagna etc?

Appreciate your inputs

Ravi

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Currently your question looks like a personal advice question which we don't entertain on this site. You may want to edit and remove personal advice text from the question body. To learn more visit help section: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help